# file:///storage/emulated/0 path on android device

Tags: android

I'm developing a file explorer for android app and want to use this path as default. 
Are all android devices have following path by default?

```
file:///storage/emulated/0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) per documentation.

Answer (score 0):

First time I hear about it. How about you follow the lead from Astro and use the external storage path as the default? Lacking that, use /.